# How to check for both WASD and arrow keys input simultaneously in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game that has similar player mechanics as [Subway Surfers](https://subwaysurfers.com/), i.e. the player switches lanes when the user gives its corresponding input.

```cs
private void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
        ChangeLane(-1);
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
        ChangeLane(1);
    }
}
```

This snippet basically checks for user input and makes the user switch lanes using `ChangeLane(int)` method, argument `-1` implies the player's switching to the left lane, and `1` implies the player's switching to the right lane.

---

##### Question:

I want to check for both <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys and arrow keys input simultaneously in my script.

What comes to mind immediately after thinking about this:

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) { ... }
```

I would like to do something that checks for both <kbd>A</kbd> and the left arrow with only one `if` check and not both separately as shown above.

---

##### What I have tried:

`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")`, but this doesn't work in this case as this value gets incremented until `1` as long as the key is pressed.

Next, `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`, this almost worked, returns `1` as soon as the key is pressed.

```cs
int horizontalInput = (int)Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

if (horizontalInput != 0) {
    ChangeLane(horizontalInput);
}
```

My Horizontal Axis in Input Manager:
[image]

##### But....

`Input.GetAxis(string)` and `Input.GetAxisRaw(string)` works similar to `Input.GetKey(KeyCode)` but I want something that works as `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode)`.

---

**PS:** I would appreciate an answer that doesn't include getting away with `boolean` flags to skip frames after the button is pressed down.

Answer (score 3):

The Unity [InputManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) allows you to specify a primary key and alternative keys for the positive and negative buttons on an axis.

You can configure your "horizontal" axis to use "w" for positive, "s" for negative, "up arrow" for alt positive, and "down arrow" for alt negative. Then you should use GetAxisRaw.

Using the InputManager allows you to abstract the configuration of inputs out of your code. The InputManager can be configured to use a controller, a racing setup, a keyboard, etc, all without having to make any modifications to your code. While it functions identically to `GetKey`, it allows you to avoid hardcoding button presses.

*A side note for why you use GetAxisRaw: GetAxis smooths input, which is why it takes some time for it to hit 1 or -1. GetAxisRaw delivers the immediate input.*

It appears that you do not actually want WASD/arrow continuous control of your character and instead want impulse control. In other words, you don't want longer button presses to further affect your character's movement. Instead, consider using [GetButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html) and define the buttons appropriately in your InputManager.

Comment: Please recognize that I did comment on why you should use the input manager in my third sentence onward. I read your entire question. @GeekyQuentin

Comment: My question clearly mentioned my use of input manager

Comment: I've updated my comment to identify GetButtonDown in the InputManager, which meets your needs. @GeekyQuentin this website is a place to debug. Rather than snarky/combative comments in response to answers that do not fully answer your question, please try to productively course correct misunderstandings.

Comment: `GetButtonDown` helped for an extent to detect a button down, but it doesn't help in finding out if <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> is pressed

Comment: You can define buttons in your input manager. The example in the documentation is "Fire1", but you can instead create and define "JumpLeft" and "JumpRight". Then you can assign those keys to those buttons.

Comment: I don't want to make four buttons, I want it to work like it returns either -1 or 1 when the button is down, and not a boolean to check if the button is down or not

Comment: May I ask how that is different than using an axis and checking if it's 0 vs. the absolute value of the raw axis?

Comment: GetButtonDown only returns true on the first frame the button is pressed, so you don't need to create additional booleans. The common standard for your use case (Subway Surfers) would be to use a screen UI button, or an InputManager button.

Comment: We can continue the discussion in chat if you still want to discuss about my question

Answer (score 2):

Use the Unity's new input system and create a new action with both left arrow and A key. You can subscribe to the action to change lane. This will check for both keys simultaneously.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the technique of dissimilarity to the previous value.

```cs
private int perviousInput; //cache last input

public void Update()
{
    int horizontalInput = (int)Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (horizontalInput == perviousInput) return;
    
    if (horizontalInput != 0) {
        Debug.Log(horizontalInput);
    }

    perviousInput = horizontalInput;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this method, what I wanted is that..., you get it when I say `Input.GetAxis` works similar to `Input.GetKey` right? The similarity is that these return `true` every frame whereas `Input.GetKeyDown` returns `true` only the frame at which the key was pressed. I am looking for something that works similar to `Input.GetKeyDown`, i.e. returning `true` only at the first frame of the key press

Comment: @GeekyQuentin If your goal is to avoid unnecessary processing, the solution to the problem is to use Unity's New Input System which works by calling events when pressed and is optimal. If you want to use the old system, I don't know if there is a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by combining inputs additively, allowing for competing inputs to be considered and cancel if they balance.  For example, if you hold A and D at the same time, do nothing.  If you press A and LeftArrow at the same time, the input this frame is Left.  Realize that you have to determine what the inputs are per-frame, accurately, then as a second step decide what to do with them.

```
int horizontal = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) 
 + Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) 
 + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.2f ? 1:0 
 - Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) 
 - Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) 
 - Input.GetAxis("Horizontal) < 0.2f ? 1:0;
horizontal = Mathf.Clamp(horizontal, -1,1);
```

Okay, so now you have a value that is -1, 0 or 1 this frame.  Next you have to decide whether your player will move or not.  If you want to handle repeated movements, which generally you do if you are supporting a joystick controller.  Usually the way I do that is have a variable in the character controller class that remembers that last time you moved and only lets you move if the repeat duration has expired.

```
private float _lastMoveTime = 0.0f;
private float const kMinMoveTime = 0.1f;  // in seconds

...
if (Time.runtimeSinceStartup - _lastMoveTime > kMinMoveTime)
{
    if (horizontal==-1 || horizontal==1)
    {
        _lastMoveTime = Time.runtimeSinceStartup;
        // move according to horizontal
    }
}
```

Finally, you want to detect when someone releases a key, and reset the timer.  Doing so means you get immediate response if holding multiple keys, but even in the single-key-held case, you don't need to wait to press the same button repeatedly.

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)
 || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow) 
 || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D) 
 || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    _lastMoveTime = 0.0f;
}
```

Note, if you always want to enforce a delay between moves, you can substitute `Time.realtimeSinceStartup - kTimeBetweenMoves` for the `0.0f` above, and you have accurate timing between presses and releases.

```
Hope this helps.
```